# Family Membership not inherited by related contacts

Tags: civimember, relationships

We have two sites recently updated to 4.6.8 and are experiencing issues with family memberships, where the related party is not getting a new membership when the other renews.

Are there any changes lately that would account for this?  It had been working previously, in 4.6.3 and earlier.

One of the sites has a number of extensions involved, but the other is pretty vanilla and they both have the same issue.

Comment: You say "not getting a new membership when the other renews" - not sure if you mean 'they don't get an extended End Date', or something else, since in theory a renewal does not add a new membership.

Comment: Thanks for asking; yes, you are correct.  The date of their membership isn't extended.

Comment: you should be able to verify if this works on the demo site

Comment: I am back to working on this. It's pretty hard to replicate in the demo site because I can't create Drupal users to mimic the member accessing the site.  Can you (or anyone) confirm that non-primary members should be able to renew an existing membership?